# Convert json string to ApolloError

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

Is there a way to convert a json string representation of an [ApolloError](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server-errors/src/index.ts#L9) into an actual ApolloError object? Or at least parse it in JS somehow?

i.e. If I have something like this:

```
const x = `{ 'message': 'message', 'locations': [{ 'line': 2, 'column': 3 }], 'path': ['path'], 'extensions': { 'errorType': 'type', 'errorCode': None, 'errorName': 'name', 'message': "",'stackTrace': None, 'operatorName': None, } }`;
```

Comment: That is not JSON. You need to use `"` instead of `'`

Comment: Where did you get that string from? Sure it's possible, but the better approach would be not to convert it into a string in the first place. Also what do you need the `ApolloError` instance for - it's not like it has useful methods or something?